# How to create a view without adding a new page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 19 buttons on a page when I click on a button it opens a new page with a view, Every button has a different view. But the problem is that I don't want to create a new page for every button I want to simply create one view and navigate data of every button on that view page. Is there any approach that I can use in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: What you could do is create these control templates in your App.xaml and then based on condition assign it to `ContentView's`

Comment: thanks i will look into it

Comment: 19 buttons is so much, but you can try with a TabbedPage.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tabbedpage?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do it. One way is to just create one page, and overload the constructor of the Page. And then you pass in the information along with each push into the constructor of that page.

Comment: thanks for suggestions..i hope it may helpful for me

Comment: One page with different templates should be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the ControlTemplate features in Xamarin.Forms. Take a look at the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template) for more details.

Otherwise, you can write style for your view and use it using the Key wherever you want.
Xamarin has a clear [documentation on Styling here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/).

I hope that helps.